# Dúvida Lógica Geração de Rodadas Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Tenho um sistema de gerenciamento de campeonatos em Laravel. O sistema funciona perfeitamente, mas estou tendo problemas ao gerar rodadas, preciso que independente do número de grupos inscritos, o sistema consiga gerar as rodadas do campeonato, eu estou fazendo da seguinte forma, mas segundo o console retorna o seguinte erro na linha 184:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
>   HELP
>   Undefined variable: rodadas

como não tenho muita experiência em Laravel, não estou sabendo escrever corretamente o código, nem definir algumas variáveis, não funciona de jeito nenhum, já estou no desespero, se alguma boa alma puder me ajudar, farei o possível para retribuir, agradeço desde já!

**RodadaAdminController.php**

```
<?php

class RodadaAdminController extends BaseController {

    public function listarGeracaoRodadas($id) {

        $equipe = Equipe::find(Auth::id());

        $totalJogadores = Jogador::join('transferencias', 'transferencias.id_jogador', '=', 'jogadores.id_jogador')
                                            ->where('transferencias.id_equipe_atual', '=', $equipe->id_equipe)
                                            ->where('flg_aprovado', '=', 1)
                                            ->groupBy('transferencias.id_jogador')
                                            ->orderBy('id_transferencia', 'DESC')
                                            ->count();

       $totalCampeonatosEmAberto = Campeonato::where('dt_inicio_inscricoes', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))
                           ->where('dt_fim_inscricoes', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
                           ->where('flg_ativo', '=', 1)
                           ->count();


      $campeonato = Campeonato::find($id);

      if($campeonato->flg_tp_campeonato == 1) {
        return self::geraJogosMunicipal($campeonato->id_campeonato);
      }

        return View::make('admin/campeonatos/geracao/gerar-rodadas')->with(
                            array(
                    'equipe' => $equipe,
                    'totalJogadores' => $totalJogadores,
                    'totalCampeonatosEmAberto' => $totalCampeonatosEmAberto,
                                'totalInscricoes' => InscricaoController::getTotalnscricao(),
                    'campeonato' => $campeonato,
                            )
                        );
    }


  public function gerarRodadas() {

    // Gerando as Rodadas do Campeonato
    foreach(Input::get('rodada') as $idJogo => $rodada) {
        $jogo = Jogo::find($idJogo);
        $jogo->nr_rodada = $rodada[0];
        $jogo->save();
    }

    $campeonato = Campeonato::find($jogo->id_campeonato);
    $campeonato->flg_andamento = 3; // Jogos criados com rodadas
    $campeonato->save();

    return Redirect::to(URL::route('admin-selecao-campeonato-jogos'))->with(array('sucesso' => 'Rodadas Criadas com Sucesso!'));

  }

  static public function geraJogosMunicipal($id) {

    $campeonato = Campeonato::find($id);

    foreach($campeonato->getGrupos as $grupo) {
        $equipes = $grupo->getEquipes()->select('id_equipe')->get();

        $qtdEquipes = count($equipes);

        if($qtdEquipes == 8){
            // Gerando a Primeira Rodada
            $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][1] = array(
                            array($equipes[0]->id_equipe, $equipes[1]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[2]->id_equipe, $equipes[3]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[4]->id_equipe, $equipes[5]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[6]->id_equipe, $equipes[7]->id_equipe),
                          );

            // Gerando a Segunda Rodada
            $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][2] = array(
                            array($equipes[7]->id_equipe, $equipes[4]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[5]->id_equipe, $equipes[6]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[3]->id_equipe, $equipes[0]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[1]->id_equipe, $equipes[2]->id_equipe),
                          );

            // Gerando a Terceira Rodada
            $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][3] = array(
                            array($equipes[6]->id_equipe, $equipes[3]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[2]->id_equipe, $equipes[5]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[4]->id_equipe, $equipes[1]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[0]->id_equipe, $equipes[7]->id_equipe),
                          );

            // Gerando a Quarta Rodada
            $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][4] = array(
                            array($equipes[1]->id_equipe, $equipes[6]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[3]->id_equipe, $equipes[4]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[7]->id_equipe, $equipes[2]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[5]->id_equipe, $equipes[0]->id_equipe),
                          );

            // Gerando a Quinta Rodada
            $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][5] = array(
                            array($equipes[0]->id_equipe, $equipes[2]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[1]->id_equipe, $equipes[3]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[4]->id_equipe, $equipes[6]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[7]->id_equipe, $equipes[5]->id_equipe),
                          );

            // Gerando a Sexta Rodada
            $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][6] = array(
                            array($equipes[6]->id_equipe, $equipes[0]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[5]->id_equipe, $equipes[1]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[3]->id_equipe, $equipes[7]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[2]->id_equipe, $equipes[4]->id_equipe),
                          );

            // Gerando a Sétima Rodada
            $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][7] = array(
                            array($equipes[7]->id_equipe, $equipes[1]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[5]->id_equipe, $equipes[3]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[6]->id_equipe, $equipes[2]->id_equipe),
                            array($equipes[4]->id_equipe, $equipes[0]->id_equipe),
                          );

          }else if($qtdEquipes == 7){

                // Gerando a Primeira Rodada
                $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][1] = array(
                                array($equipes[1]->id_equipe, $equipes[2]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[3]->id_equipe, $equipes[4]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[5]->id_equipe, $equipes[6]->id_equipe),
                                //array($equipes[6]->id_equipe (Folga 0)
                              );

                // Gerando a Segunda Rodada
                $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][2] = array(
                                array($equipes[2]->id_equipe, $equipes[3]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[4]->id_equipe, $equipes[5]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[0]->id_equipe, $equipes[6]->id_equipe),
                                //array($equipes[5]->id_equipe (Folga 1)
                              );

                // Gerando a Terceira Rodada
                $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][3] = array(
                                array($equipes[3]->id_equipe, $equipes[6]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[1]->id_equipe, $equipes[5]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[0]->id_equipe, $equipes[4]->id_equipe),
                                //array($equipes[4]->id_equipe (Folga 2)
                              );

                // Gerando a Quarta Rodada
                $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][4] = array(
                                array($equipes[1]->id_equipe, $equipes[4]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[0]->id_equipe, $equipes[5]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[2]->id_equipe, $equipes[6]->id_equipe),
                                //array($equipes[3]->id_equipe (Folga 3)
                              );

                // Gerando a Quinta Rodada
                $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][5] = array(
                                array($equipes[2]->id_equipe, $equipes[5]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[0]->id_equipe, $equipes[3]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[1]->id_equipe, $equipes[6]->id_equipe),
                                //array($equipes[2]->id_equipe (Folga 4)
                              );

                // Gerando a Sexta Rodada
                $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][6] = array(
                                array($equipes[4]->id_equipe, $equipes[6]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[1]->id_equipe, $equipes[3]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[0]->id_equipe, $equipes[2]->id_equipe),
                                //array($equipes[1]->id_equipe (Folga 5)
                              );

                // Gerando a Sétima Rodada
                $rodadas[$grupo->id_grupo][7] = array(
                                array($equipes[0]->id_equipe, $equipes[1]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[2]->id_equipe, $equipes[4]->id_equipe),
                                array($equipes[3]->id_equipe, $equipes[5]->id_equipe),
                                //array($equipes[0]->id_equipe (Folga 6)
                              );
        }
    }   

    foreach($rodadas as $idGrupo => $jogos) {
      foreach($jogos as $nrRodada => $jg) {
        foreach($jg as $eqs) {
          reset($eqs);
          $eq1 = $eqs[key($eqs)];

          end($eqs);
          $eq2 = $eqs[key($eqs)];
          $jogo = new Jogo;
          $jogo->id_campeonato = $campeonato->id_campeonato;
          $jogo->id_equipe1 = $eq1;
          $jogo->id_equipe2 = $eq2;
          $jogo->id_grupo = $idGrupo;
          $jogo->flg_tp_jogo = 1;
          $jogo->nr_rodada = $nrRodada;
          $jogo->flg_ativo = 1;
          $jogo->save();
          echo $eq1.' x '.$eq2.'<br>';
        }
      }
    }

    $campeonato = Campeonato::find($jogo->id_campeonato);
    $campeonato->flg_andamento = 3; // Jogos criados com rodadas teste
    $campeonato->save();


    return Redirect::to(URL::route('admin-selecao-campeonato-jogos'))->with(array('sucesso' => 'Rodadas Criadas com Sucesso!'));

  }
}
```

**gerar-rodadas.blade.php**

```
@extends('admin/template')
@section('content')
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="{{ URL::route('dashboard') }}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Campeonatos</a></li>
    <li class="active">Geração de Rodadas</li>
  </ol>
  <h1>Geração de Rodadas</h1>
  @if( Session::has('sucesso') )
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{{ Session::get('sucesso') }}}
    </div>
  @endif
  @if( Session::has('warning') )
      <div class="alert alert-warning">
          {{ Session::get('warning') }}
      </div>
  @endif
  @if ( count($errors) > 0)
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <strong>Erro: </strong>
          @foreach ($errors->all() as $e)
             {{ $e }}
          @endforeach
      </div>
  @endif
  {{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::route('post-gerar-rodadas', $campeonato->id_campeonato), 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      @foreach($campeonato->getGrupos as $grupo)
      @if(!isset($nr_divisao) || $grupo->nr_divisao != $nr_divisao)     
      <?php $grupos[] = $grupo->nr_divisao ?>
      <li><a href="#div{{ $grupo->nr_divisao }}" data-toggle="tab">{{ GrupoAdminController::getDivisao($grupo->nr_divisao, $grupo->id_campeonato) }}</a></li>
      @endif
      <?php $nr_divisao = $grupo->nr_divisao; ?>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      @foreach($campeonato->getGrupos as $divisao)
        <div id="div{{$divisao}}" class="tab-pane">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Buscar Jogo</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="buscarTabela">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <hr>
            @foreach($campeonato->getGrupos()->where('nr_divisao', '=', $divisao)->get() as $grupo)
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Grupo {{ $grupo->nm_grupo }}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <?php $x = 1; ?>
                  @foreach($grupo->getJogos as $jogo)
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                          <h3 class="panel-title">{{{ str_limit($jogo->getJogadorHome()->first()->nm_equipe, 20) }}} x {{{ str_limit($jogo->getJogadorAway()->first()->nm_equipe, 20) }}}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          <?php
                            $totJogos = count($grupo->getJogos);
                            $totEquipes = floor($grupo->getEquipes()->count() / 2);
                          ?>
                          Selecione uma rodada
                          <select name="rodada[{{ $jogo->id_jogo }}][]  " class="form-control">
                            @for($i = 1; $i <= floor($totJogos / $totEquipes); ++$i)
                            <option {{ ($i == $x) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }} value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }} Rodada</option>
                            @endfor
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                      if($x == floor($totJogos / $totEquipes)) {
                        $x = 0;
                      }
                      $x++;
                    ?>
                  @endforeach
                </div>
              </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
      @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-success">Gerenciar Rodadas</button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <hr>
  {{ Form::close() }}
@stop

@section('scripts')
$('input[name="buscarTabela"]').on('keyup', function() {
    var vlrBusca = this;
    $.each($(this).parents('.tab-pane').find('.panel'), function() {
        $(this).show();
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(vlrBusca).val().toLowerCase()) == -1) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
@stop
```

Comment: Coloque o erro por favor

Comment: desculpe, havia esquecido! Adicionei à pergunta.

Comment: Provavelmente você está testando com `$qtdEquipes` diferente de 7 e 8, não entrando nas condições que definem a variável `$rodadas`. E se a quantidade de equipes for 3, o que deveria ser `$rodadas`?

Comment: entendi, como é um campeonato de futsal teríamos que adicionar uma quantidade minima de equipes para que o script consiga gerar as rodadas dos jogos, certo?

Comment: Isso já é requisito do projeto e deve ser discutido com a equipe responsável. Só apontei onde está o erro de lógica que deve ser resolvido.

Comment: entendo, o projeto é particular, por isso estou procurando ajuda, agradeço a dica!

Comment: esse erro acontece no controller ou na view?

Comment: consegui corrigir o erro, mas não consegui fazer a função do jeito que precisava :(